# tomcat7 - unable to connect remotely to server (port 8080: Connection refused)

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I am using [PerfSONAR](http://www.perfsonar.net/about/what-is-perfsonar/) a network measurement tool, which has a UI that depends on tomcat7. I installed the [perfsonar-ui](http://docs.perfsonar.net/install_psui.html) on an Ubuntu 14.04 server, and to test my installation I pointed my browser (on a windows 7 machine) to the address `http://my_server_address:8080/perfsonar-ui/`. The connection failed.

**What I tried so far:**

- pings from multiple machines to my server were successful.
- on the server itself, `curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/perfsonar-ui/`, response status OK (200)
- on other servers, `curl -X GET http://my_server_address:8080/perfsonar-ui/` results in:

  `curl: (7) Failed to connect to my_server_address port 8080: Connection refused`
- allowed port 8080 on the server `sudo ufw allow 8080`
- disabled the firewall on the server `sudo ufw disable`
- i am binding to `0.0.0.0`, so the connector from my `/etc/tomcat7/server.xml` file looks like:

  `<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" address="0.0.0.0" />`
- `netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN` result:

  `tcp    0   0 0.0.0.0:8080    0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN    -`

Still not working! :(

Can someone help me troubleshoot the issue, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am closing this. It had nothing to do with tomcat. It was an iptables issue, I had to allow incoming connections to destination port 8080. It worked!

Comment: @ShrikantShete when I installed the perfsonar-toolkit-security package, the iptables were configured with some default rules. So I had to add a rule (and put it a the top) to allow incoming traffic to port 8080. Hope this was clear and helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a alternate solution just replacing the port 8080 with the port 80 in server.xml in tomcat conf. Then stop and start the tomcat server again. It is tested on Ubuntu 16.4 server.

ORIGINAL:
Connector **port="8080"** protocol="HTTP/1.1"

MODIFIED:
Connector **port="80"** protocol="HTTP/1.1"

It works for me when i access remote tomcat sever using CURL from my website.

API URL should be "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/24" in place of "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/api/24"